# Error: The non-abstract class 'S' is missing implementations for these members

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, i18next, fileversioninfo

Error: The non-abstract class 'S' is missing implementations for these members:
i18n.dart:11

- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemDown
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemLeft
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemRight
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToEnd
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToStart
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemUp
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class S implements WidgetsLocalizations {
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:173:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemDown' is defined here.
String get reorderItemDown;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:177:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemLeft' is defined here.
String get reorderItemLeft;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:181:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemRight' is defined here.
String get reorderItemRight;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:165:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToEnd' is defined here.
String get reorderItemToEnd;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:161:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToStart' is defined here.
String get reorderItemToStart;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:169:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemUp' is defined here.
String get reorderItemUp;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The non-abstract class '$en' is missing implementations for these members:
i18n.dart:26

- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemDown
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemLeft
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemRight
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToEnd
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToStart
- WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemUp
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class $en extends S {
^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:173:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemDown' is defined here.
String get reorderItemDown;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:177:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemLeft' is defined here.

String get reorderItemLeft;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:181:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemRight' is defined here.
String get reorderItemRight;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:165:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToEnd' is defined here.
String get reorderItemToEnd;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:161:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemToStart' is defined here.

String get reorderItemToStart;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:169:14: Context: 'WidgetsLocalizations.reorderItemUp' is defined here.

String get reorderItemUp;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Field 'wLanguage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
file_version_info.dart:13
external int? wLanguage;
^
: Error: Field 'wCodePage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
external int? wCodePage;
^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Can someone expert help me with these issues, I can't find any solutions.